# Is there a cups PHP API?

Tags: php, printing, cups

I need to make a print on cups printer from my PHP web application. Is there a PHP API for cups? In my server `shell_exec()` and all such functions are strictly disabled. So I cant print using `lpr`. Please advice

Comment: how would an api help if you cant print local?

Comment: I have successfully printed using a C program.It's using CUPS API

Comment: There is a small and uncomplete lib "PHP PrintIPP" here: http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/usage

Comment: Actually the interface best suited for your purpose is CUPS http interface!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's available. We can do it by [PHP::PRINT::IPP](http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/) 

Sample Code

`<?php 
   require_once(PrintIPP.php); 
   $ipp = new PrintIPP(); $ipp->setHost("localhost"); 
   $ipp->setPrinterURI("/printers/epson"); 
   $ipp->setData("./testfiles/test-utf8.txt"); // Path to file. 
   $ipp->printJob(); 
?>`